# How to get a value out of a hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have the following hash (`@myhash`) in Ruby:

```
[
  {
    "id"        => "123456789",
    "name"      =>"Random name", 
    "list_type" =>"random type of list"
  }
]
```

How can take the value of the id out of the hash? (Basically my result should be: 123456789)

- When I try doing `@myhash[:id]` I get the following error "can't convert Symbol into Integer"
- When I try doing `@myhash['id']` I get the following error "can't convert String into Integer"

I've tried adding `.to_i`, `.to_s` and etc. but nothing helps.

Comment: Get your terminology straight. You got a ruby hash, not a rails hash. Ruby is a language. Rails is a library/framework written in Ruby. It's like saying "I program in jQuery". No, you program in Javascript and you *use* jQuery.

Comment: I understand that it may all look the same to you, since you're new. But please, learn to distinguish the two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have there is not a hash. It's an array of hashes (well, array of one hash, to be precise).

First you have to address proper element in the array (first one), then address its value by key.

```
@myhash[0]['id'] # => '123456789'
# or
@myhash.first['id'] # => '123456789'
```

> I get the following error "can't convert Symbol into Integer"

You think you're working with hash, but in reality, it's the array. Arrays don't accept string or symbols keys. They want integers for the index. Hence the error.

Comment: A downvote? How can this post be improved?

Comment: How about if I have an array with more than 1 hash and I would like to take the ids of each hash in that array and form a new array (I need all ids, not first id only)?

Comment: `arr.map{|h| h['id'] }` - something like this

Answer (score 2):

Ruby [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html) looks like `{}`, while `[]` is [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html). Your object is array with first and only item being hash. To access it use the following:

```
@myhash.first['id'] # 123456789'
```